# Can you download the Hanyu Da Cidian (漢語大詞典) as E-book format or PDF?

Tags: resources

Unquestionably, an e-book format is way more convenient than these physical volumes or CDs! Where can I obtain 漢語大詞典 as E-Book?

[image]

Comment: Pleco offers a digital download of 漢語大詞典 for a price tag. Only the quotes and headers are in Traditional Chinese though; the text of the definitions are in Simplified Chinese, which can get a bit annoying and confusing when you're trying to relate quotes to definitions.

Comment: @dROOOze This is an "excellent answer".

Comment: You'll find twelve tomes on libgen if you search for the simplified title "汉语大词典". Each tome is around 200 MB, so I think it's unpractical to have it all in a single PDF.

Comment: You can try to download an [android app](https://www.wandoujia.com/apps/8111349) which is also very convenient.

Comment: The vast majority of books in China do not come out electronically unless someone scans them.